Accuracy of localization in the Molecular Orbital Theory
When I was looking about how the Molecular Orbital Theory complements the Valence Bond Theory, It talked about how they specialize at certain properties like how VB well explains chemical reactivty of alkanes very well while it is more complicated in the MO theory (due to the delocalized MOs).
Then it started talking about Natural Bond Theory / localized Molecular Orbitals - how localization can exist in MO theory.
Now the Question is I am wondering the accuracy of this Theory - It contradicts the main principle of MO theory which is how MO are delocalized across a molecule.
How accurate is this, in describing chemical properties and what happens when atoms covalently bond - either through direct analysis or Quantum Chemistry studies or both.
